# IntelliJ run configuration for Grails environment

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I want to create a run configuration that will execute `run-app` in a custom environment named "demo". The following works fine on the command-line

```
grails run-app -Dgrails.env=demo
```

But inside IntelliJ, if I enter either

```
run-app -Dgrails.env=demo
```

or

```
-Dgrails.env=demo run-app
```

in the "Command line" field of the "Run/Debug Configuration" dialog, neither of them start the app in the correct environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run Configuration dialog has separated text fields for jvm options and command arguments. You have to put '-Dgrails.env=demo' to 'VM options' field.

Comment: Tried this using Intellij 2016.2 and Grails 3.2.0.M2 without any luck.  What did work was putting `run-app -Dgrails.env=prod` in the "Command line" field as the OP had originally tried.  Also worked from the command line.